# Add offset to rows to get monotonically increasing values

Tags: sql, oracle

based on this thread ([Check rows for monotonically increasing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096292/check-rows-for-monotonically-increasing-values)), I have an additional requirement:
The value-column represents a counter.
In my application, due to some annoying reason, the counter value gets reset from time to time, i.e. starts from zero. For data evaluation, I need the accumulated value of all counts. My idea was to create an additional column that contains the accumulated value.
As long as no reset occurs, the value of the new column is the same as of the original value column. After a reset, the value of the new column is the latest accumulated value + the current counter value. Multiple resets may occur in the data. Once again, rows with the same "name" belong to the same measurement and have to be handled sorted by meas_date.

This is the original data:

```
id   name   meas_date   value
1    name1  2018/01/01  1
2    name1  2018/01/02  2
3    name2  2018/01/04  2
4    name1  2018/01/03  1
5    name1  2018/01/04  5
6    name2  2018/01/05  4
7    name2  2018/01/06  2
8    name1  2018/01/05  2
```

Desired result would be

```
id   name   meas_date   value  accumulated_value
1    name1  2018/01/01  1      1
2    name1  2018/01/02  2      2
3    name2  2018/01/04  2      2
4    name1  2018/01/03  1      3 
5    name1  2018/01/04  5      7
6    name2  2018/01/05  4      4
7    name2  2018/01/06  2      6
8    name1  2018/01/05  2      9
```

The LAG function from the thread mentioned above is really helpful to find the rows where the counter value was reset. But now, I am struggling to combine this with the accumulation of the values to get the overall counter values.

Thank you very much,

Christian

Comment: Why? If you just want to see this in the output, add rownum to the selected attributes. There are just too many race conditions to be certain that the DBMS will generate monotonically increasing numbers from a counter. If you are happy to cripple the database performance you could restrict inserts/updates to a procedure with an autonomous transaction and heavy locking.

Comment: This may seem like an odd question but, what is causing the "value" field to reset? Would not the prudent course of action be to just fix that issue and use that? (Assuming the reset is not intentional)

Comment: I guess the word "counter" was misleading. I do not need a counter like an increasing index on the rows, therefore rownum does not help. The counter-value contains the number of events that have occured at a day (specified by meas_date) on a test bench. For evaluation of overall # of events, mean # per day, week etc per test bench, I need the accumulated # of events from start of measurement until every day of the measurement.

Comment: The reset is intentional in some cases, not intended in others. The problem that leads to not intended cases will be fixed, but there are many stake holders involved and it takes some time. From the past, I have many millions of measurements that I need to work with, therefore I am looking for what I described above.

Comment: @Christian - How do you get accumulated_value = 3 in row# 4? Should that be 4 = value in row1+row2+row4? Or stay at 1 because measure dates are different.

Comment: row1 and row2 have increasing values (1,2) which means there was no reset. In row 4, the value is less then than in row2, therefore it was reset. The last "valid" value (row2) has to be used as offset. So 3 is correct as this is 2 (offset from row2) + 1 (current value from row4). meas_date is used for sorting only, not for filtering or grouping.

Comment: You can't use row2 > row1 as proof there was no reset. There could have been 1 event for row 1, a reset, then 2 events for row 2, if I'm understanding your construction.

Comment: The real situation is a bit more complex, I just simplified it for this question. With the real data, I can decide if there was a reset or not.

Comment: @Christian - continuing with questions. And how did you get 7 in row 5?  The row 5 is increasing row according to your logic. Should that stay at 5?. I was able to get correct results till row 4 with LAG() function simply adding the value of current row and prev row in case when current row is less than prev row value. This way the values in row 4 is 1-current val and prev value is 2, which gives correct result.

Comment: @Art - For name1: row1 and row2 is straightforward, accumulated value is 1 and 2 since no reset occured. row4 has a reset, the counter starts from zero. Accumulated value is "old" value (from row2) + new value => 2+1=3. row5 has no reset compared to row4, therefore accumulated value is "old" value + new value => 2+5=7 (row2+row5). In row9, another reset occured. Accumulated value is now row2+row5+row9 = 2+5+2=9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found a solution which takes two steps:

```
-- 1. set flag column = 2 for all rows with values right before an reset
update TEST dst set dst.flag = (
  with src as (
    SELECT id, name, value,
    CASE WHEN value < value_next THEN 0 ELSE 2 END AS flag
    FROM (
      SELECT id, name, value,
      LEAD(value, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY name order by meas_date) AS value_next
      FROM TEST
    )      
  )
  select src.flag from src where dst.id = src.id
) 

-- 2. Use SQL for Modeling to calculate the accumulated values
SELECT  name, meas_date, value, offset, value+offset as accumulated_value
FROM TEST 
MODEL RETURN UPDATED ROWS
 PARTITION BY (name) 
 DIMENSION BY (meas_date, flag)
 MEASURES (value, 0 as offset)
 RULES (
  offset[meas_date, ANY] ORDER BY meas_date = NVL(sum(NVL(value,0))[meas_date < CV(meas_date), flag=2],0) 
 );
```

After step 1:

```
id  name    meas_date   value flag
1   name1   01.01.18    1     0
2   name1   02.01.18    2     2
3   name2   04.01.18    2     0
4   name1   03.01.18    1     0
5   name1   04.01.18    5     2
6   name2   05.01.18    4     2
7   name2   06.01.18    2     2
8   name1   05.01.18    2     2
```

Output of step 2

```
name    meas_date   value  offset  accumulated_value
name1   01.01.18    1      0       1
name1   02.01.18    2      0       2
name1   03.01.18    1      2       3
name1   04.01.18    5      2       7
name1   05.01.18    2      7       9
name2   04.01.18    2      0       2
name2   05.01.18    4      0       4
name2   06.01.18    2      4       6
```

Comment: Show the output please.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?

```
select id, name, meas_date, value,  sum(value) over(partition by meas_date order by meas_date, value )  from #temp 
group by id, name, meas_date, value
order by meas_date,   value
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not take into account, that not all values have to be accumulated. Instead, an offset needs to be applied. The offset for a consecutive set of rows (with respect to meas_date) is the sum of all "last" values of all previous sets of rows. A set here means consecutive rows without a reset in value.